# Количество активных пользователей и использование JSON API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Всем привет.

Есть аккаунт МойСклад. Используется 6 пользователей. Все они активно работают в интерфейсе МС. Настроена интеграция по JSON API. Постоянно выскакивает сообщение об ошибке, что "превышен лимит одновременных подключений", с чем это может быть связано?
Как учитываются одновременные подключения?

Comment: Уточните номер ошибки

Comment: Нет номера ошибки. Это видят пользователи у себя на экране во время работы с  МойСклад http://joxi.ru/EA4W69Sopn3O2b Они почему-то их связывают с процессом интеграции по АПИ.

Comment: Можете более подробно описать проблему? Вы используете один аккаунт для всех пользователей или у каждого пользователя свой отдельный аккаунт (логин и пароль)? По аудиту входа на аккаунте (см вкладку аудит) в систему не попадает какой-либо другой пользователь? Пробовали ли обратиться в службу поддержки МойСклад для разьяснения проблем? Пока что очень похоже, что ошибка не в апи.

Comment: к сожалению, поддержка МойСклад отправляет сюда. По всем вопросам... Кроме скринов от пользователя другой информации, к сожалению, нет...